# Why is text line breaking—when cutting and pasting in the console—so much slower than in any other application?

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, zsh, speed

I often work with Vim, but sometimes I feel that I can do certain things better in [Kate](https://kate-editor.org). So I copy the file from vim via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and paste it into Kate.

This way, everything is pretty fast. But if I repaste it to Vim, the pasting-process becomes terribly slow even when using `:set paste`.

I somehow understand that, since Vim does a lot of stuff, but it’s not only Vim. But in other applications, I’ve seen the same. Pasting stuff into the MYSQL server is very slow, too. The same with bash and Zsh.

I don’t understand why pasting text that needs automatic line-breaks with long texts in graphical applications is (almost always) faster than in the command line. Isn’t there way more calculation involved in doing that in the GUI? I mean, technically, the command line is a block of very big pixels (which can display single letters each). The command-line-resolution is way less than the one of the GUI, so it should be faster.

Comment: Does it speed up if you do a "`:syntax off`" before pasting?

Comment: @Heptite: he says it happens  in other apps -- mysql, bash and zsh... though I wonder what bash+zsh he is running.  Native or cygwin, and what window he is running in (cmd.exe) or a cygwin tty window, or some other TTY-emulator.  Best I found is SecureCRT -- costs for a license, but its worth it for me... I usually use it when I do tty-work on windows/cygwin.  As well as my primary tty for logging into linux (emulates linux and other terms).

Answer (score -2):

There is a GUI version of vim (gvim), including one for Windows (as well as one for 'Cygwin' that runs on the X-GUI (that also runs on windows).

I'd try the native gvim and see if that gives you the speed you are looking for.

Note: I don't think the newest vims run in the console at all (too many problems). (Clarification: the cygwin version doesn't run in the Windows cmd.exe -- no terminal support.  It does run in a regular TTY emulator as well as the cygwin tty emulators and under cygwin-X -- best would likely be cygwin-X -- I run my linux-gvim sessions, exclusively through cygwin's X.  My connection to my server is "internal" (not exposed to internet), so I don't need to use encryption, so it runs plenty fast.

To better answer the original poster's Question though, there are some unknowns -- like what console he is talking about and when he mentions zsh & bash, is he talking about cygwin versions, or ones running under the win10-linux subsystem, or what?

Originally thought problem might be the console you were using, so recommended trying the native versions, but as for why consoles are slower -- I touch on that below.  Remember: even if you run a text console -- it is still, likely
running on the windows desktop.  So it is a GUI-emulation of a text console window -- not an actual-hardware based console like the old-pre-windows DOS consoles used to be (which used graphics hardware to do scrolling, for example).  As for native vim versions:

Try https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/

I'd recommend this version:
http://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/complete-x64.exe

If you don't care about how to get your pasting faster into vim, but only want the answer of why the console is slower --- the gui, can accept pasted text directly without going through a single-character-by-single-character read/write interface (the console).  Going through the console involves reading & writing single-characters, 1 at a time.  I.e. the paste goes into *windows* (the OS), which turns it into a stream of single-characters sent to the input driver in the console.  Those go into a system buffer (not vim).  Then vim has to read those characters from the system.  While you can read / write multiple characters, they are still processed and displayed 1 at a time by the underlying SW.  Very inefficient.  When vim updates the console -- it is writing the characters and outputting tty-movement codes (not so much on input) to move text around.  Everything is handled by turning graphical actions into character codes that are sent to the console, that interprets the character codes in order to simulate a TTY.

On top of that, it still will do the normal processing that vim does -- but to see which has a larger impact, running the GUI version of vim will cut out all the console stuff.

On top of the normal slowness of a simulated console, the console in Windows has is running in Windows -- and Windows has been adding more layers of indirection since XP.  At least 1 was added in XP,  a reasonable small/fast layer, but going to vista/win7, very noticeable per-key delay was added.  Those delays happen for each key!  From what I understand, more layers were added for Win10 to allow for cloud & remote device indirection.

As far as the paste in the GUI version of vim -- it has indirections added, but they are for the entire paste-message (not per character).  So vim gets the entire pasted text that it can process without updating the screen with each character -- so only 1 screen update is *needed* after the pasted text has been processed.  More may be done, depending on speed of processing and video speed -- i.e. vim sometimes shows partial progress when things take longer, but I believe that is a toggle-able option in vim.

Comment: The newest vim absolutely does run in the console. I use (g)vim 8.0 both on Linux and Windows 7.

Comment: I mean from a command prompt, both under Windows and Linux. There is no such program as windows-cmd.exe.

Comment: @HerbWolfe: You are right.  Just tried my 8.0.163 version in cmd.exe... MS-Winx64... no prob.  Now what the heck was I thinking of... Hmmm...(never doubted it ran in Linux.. just not sure which version had probs in cmd.exe now.  Hmmm...AH! the cygwin version doesn't seem to do so well.  formatting wrong...maybe term is set wrong...

Comment: @HerbWolfe -- its the cygwin console version -- won't display properly under cmd.exe.  Can't use 'ansi', 'xterm', 'dumb' or iris-ansi.  (or "builtin_" before each of those choices -- tried both).  It will work in a cygwin-xterm-console, but not the native one.  (not that such is a big deal to me... I rarely run vim in a console -- too limited, poor color selection, can't as easily resize, slower... etc... )

Comment: I use the standard vim in a conemu window.

Comment: conemu?  Not familiar w/that one.  But a standard vim in a windows7 cmd.exe seems to work fine as well.

Comment: Lose the commentary from your answer and I will reverse my downvote.  I am not interested in a discussion.  This answer should be improved.

Comment: @HerbWolfe:  no such command as cmd.exe on windows?  Maybe you don't have your path set correctly?  Look  at C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe .